# Grails Failed Login Not Redirecting

Tags: grails, websphere

We have a Grails 1.3.7 app that uses LDAP and a custom login screen to handle security and authorization. User roles are set up in `web.xml` and mapped to groups on our WAS 8 server.

After upgrading to Grails 2.1.0, we've noticed that a failed login does not redirect to the appropriate gsp page, in our case fail_login.gsp. Instead the URL changes to fail_login.gsp but the actual page being rendered is the original login.gsp.

The web.xml file was generated using `grails install-templates` and the only changes to it were adding the security roles, security constraints, and login config sections.

```
<security-role>
    <description>View</description>
    <role-name>VIEW</role-name>
</security-role>
    <security-role>
    <description>Admin</description>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>user</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>VIEW</role-name>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Java EE Login</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.gsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/fail_login.gsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Our UrlMappings.groovy is the same as the 1.3.7 version.

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error_beam')
    "404"(controller: "error", action: "notFound")
    "403"(view:'/fail_login')
    "/log4jAdmin/dynamicLog4jAdmin.gsp"(controller: 'log4jAdmin', action: 'log4jAdmin')
    "/dynamicLog4jAdmin.gsp"(controller: 'log4jAdmin', action: 'log4jAdmin')
}
}
```

From what I've read online `<form-error-page>/fail_login.gsp</form-error-page>` in web.xml should redirect to that page if there are any issues with the login. And if nothing else 403 errors should map to that page as well. Logging in works fine so it is not an issue with the security roles or their mappings. Any thoughts?

[UPDATE]
It looks like the web.xml is not able to find the fail_login.gsp page in its current directory `/views/fail_login.gsp`. Moving both the login and fail_login pages to be under `/web-app/gsps` fixes the issue with fail_login.gsp not being rendered, but it also alters the login URL which might be a deal breaker. I can't find any documentation about where web.xml looks for the gsps in the form-login-config section, specifically whether it should be different between Grails 1.3.7 and 2.1.0